# Setting up JMenu, I'm trying to create a menu at the top of the layout box that isnt a combobox

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, menu, menubar

This is what I used to set up just the menu, I wanted to figure this out before I finished the rest of my application.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Layout_Manager extends JPanel{
    //instance variables for panels
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel panel3;
    private JPanel panel4;
    private JPanel panel5;
    private JPanel panel6;
    //instance variables for help and shapes tab
    private JMenu shapesMenu;
    private JMenu helpMenu;
    private JMenuBar Bar1;
    private JMenuItem menuItem;
    private JMenuItem CircleMenuItem;
    private JMenuItem RectangleMenuItem;
    private JMenuItem SquareMenuItem;
    private JMenuItem LineMenuItem;
    Layout_Manager(){
        //set up panel
        panel1 =new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        //Create MenuBar and add menu to it
        Bar1 = new JMenuBar();
        shapesMenu = new JMenu("Shapes");
        CircleMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Circle");
        CircleMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_C));
        RectangleMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Rectangle");
        RectangleMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK, KeyEvent.VK_R)); 
        SquareMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Square");
        SquareMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_S));
        LineMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Line");
        LineMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_L));
        shapesMenu.add(CircleMenuItem,RectangleMenuItem);
        shapesMenu.add(SquareMenuItem,LineMenuItem);
        JMenu add = Bar1.add(shapesMenu);
        panel1.add(Bar1);
        panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel3= new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel4= new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
        panel5.add(panel1);
        panel5.add(panel2);
        panel5.add(panel3);
        panel5.add(panel4);

        add(panel5);

}           
}
```

I added the other panels with the intention of the other panels helping shape the layout manager but I can't quite figure out why it doesn't create a menu????

this is my tester too, I followed examples that I have used before that have worked, which is why this is throwing me for a loop.

```
import javax.swing.*;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author ethubbard
 */
public class GUI_ShapeTester {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Manager");
        Layout_Manager layout = new Layout_Manager();
        frame.add(layout);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(null);
    }

}
```

I thought this is all I had to do to create the GUI and have only the menu bar at the top, clearly I am missing another component but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

You're not building your menus / menuitems correctly. Also the `JMenuBar` should be added to the `JFrame` with `setJMenuBar()` method. Please see below corrected code of your Layout_Manager constructor :

```
 Layout_Manager(){
        //set up panel
        panel1 =new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        //Create MenuBar and add menu to it
        Bar1 = new JMenuBar();
        shapesMenu = new JMenu("Shapes");
        CircleMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Circle");
        CircleMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_C));
        RectangleMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Rectangle");
        RectangleMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK, KeyEvent.VK_R)); 
        SquareMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Square");
        SquareMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_S));
        LineMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Line");
        LineMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_L));
        shapesMenu.add(CircleMenuItem);     // corrected
        shapesMenu.add(RectangleMenuItem);  // corrected
        shapesMenu.add(SquareMenuItem);     // corrected
        shapesMenu.add(LineMenuItem);       // corrected
        Bar1.add(shapesMenu);               // corrected
        panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel3= new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel4= new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
        panel5.add(panel1);
        panel5.add(panel2);
        panel5.add(panel3);
        panel5.add(panel4);        
        add(panel5);      
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Manager");   //create JFrame
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setJMenuBar(Bar1);                       // add menu bar built earlier
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Then from your GUI_ShapeTester class you could simply create a Layout_Manager object, eg :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Layout_Manager();
    }
```